# Writing uncompressed TGA to file in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am writing OpenGL FBO content to TGA file.I read pixels in BGR format and saving to uncompressed TGA.The weird thing is that if I save monotone colors (no textures) my exporter writes ok,but if the  pixel data comes from a texture I am getting result as is depicted in the following image:
[image: Corrupted export]

And this is the correct export which I managed to get using FreeImage lib:

```
    FIBITMAP *img = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits(pixels,_frameWidth,_frameHeight, 3 * _frameWidth , 24,FI_RGBA_RED_MASK, FI_RGBA_GREEN_MASK, FI_RGBA_BLUE_MASK,0);
    FreeImage_Save(FIF_TARGA ,img,concatString.c_str());
```

[image: Correct export]

So I suspect something is wrong with my TGA exporting code:

```
        GLubyte header[18]={0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    header[12] = _frameWidth         & 0xFF;
    header[13] = ( _frameWidth >> 8)  & 0xFF;
    header[14] = (_frameHeight)       & 0xFF; 
    header[15] = (_frameHeight >> 8)  & 0xFF;
    header[16] = 24; 
    // write out the TGA header
    fwrite(header,sizeof(GLubyte),18,shot);
    //write out the data:
    fwrite(pixels,sizeof(GLubyte),  _frameWidth * _frameHeight * 3 ,shot);
    fclose(shot);
```

What is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the bug.It was wrong file open mode!

```
    shot=fopen(concatString.c_str(),"w");
```

when it had to be :

```
    shot=fopen(concatString.c_str(),"wb");
```

"wb" - as we intend to open binary file.

FreeImage did it right because it opens the file internally.

Comment: Heh, that one requires some research :-)

Comment: I don't think that can be the problem, since sizeof(GLubyte) is 1. But you're right the problem is almost certainly in the collection of the "pixel" data rather than the writing out the data.

Comment: Are you sure that was the only change you made? I would expect sizeof(GLubyte) == 1. Did you change _frameWidth for instance?

Comment: I still believe it's the stride.

Comment: Sorry guys , my bad.This indeed was not the cause...it was even more stupid thing....  :P

Comment: @Michael IV, as I said, you had some extra bytes in there :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the pitch/stride is wrong in your code.

Comment: What kind of answer is that?

Comment: I'm talking about the buffer holding the image data. Here is better pitch/stride explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The buffer is fine.I read BGR into byte array of the size =framewidth * frameheight & 3.

Comment: Yes, I know you are filling the buffer of that size, but are you reading it right? The image suggests that you should add/skip some padding bytes before copying the second line of data. Btw, did you try to save the image data as 24-bit bitmap and then opening it with some application like Paint.NET or similar?

Comment: I can see that. Even the distorted image shows that the data is correct. When you (somehow) get your decompressed data, you have a buffer holding the data 'pixels'. Do you have any other information about that image beside width, height, bit depth... Some info in some sort of structure describing the image... If you do, can you dump the values here?

Comment: I found the bug.See my answer.I allocated byte array of the wrong size.Still it is strange why FreeType did it right..